# The method binarySearch(ArrayList<String>, int, int, String) is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I am struggling with a bit of homework.  I have fixed all of my problems with the exception of this one.  After scouring the site, I have decided to just ask my own question.

The code is designed to make a little menu that asks the user if they would like to enter an email into a database, search for a previously entered email, or quit.

My problem occurs when I try to do a binary search to determine if an email is already in the database.

The error is in the 2nd line of the addNewEmail method (The last one).
Thank you in advance for help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class project14_Brady {

    private static final int ADD = 1;
    private static final int SEARCH = 2;
    private static final int QUIT = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        ArrayList<String> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        int size = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Priming read
        int menu = menuChoice(input);
        while(menu != QUIT)
        {
            if (menu == ADD)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the email address");
                String email = input.nextLine();
                size = addNewEmail(emailAddresses, size, email);
            }
            else if (menu == SEARCH)
            {
                String email = autoComplete(emailAddresses, size, input);
                if (email != null)
                    System.out.println("Found: " + email);
                else
                    System.out.println("No matching email was found");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Unanticipated case");
            }

            // priming read
            menu = menuChoice(input);

        } // end while

    }

    public static String autoComplete(ArrayList<String> data, int size, Scanner input)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the first letters, one at a time");
        String start = "";

        while (true)
        {
            String read = input.nextLine();
            start += read;

            System.out.println("DEBUG: " + start);

            int count=0;
            String result="";

            for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
            {
                System.out.println("DEBUG: " + data.get(i));
                if (data.get(i).startsWith(start))
                {
                    result = data.get(i); // keep just the last one
                    System.out.println(data.get(i));
                    ++count;
                }

            }

            if (count == 1)
                return result;

            if (count == 0)
                return null;

        }
    }

    public static int menuChoice(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        System.out.println("Please choose from the following menu of choices:");
        System.out.println("1. Enter a new email address");
        System.out.println("2. Find an existing email address");
        System.out.println("3. Quit.");
        System.out.println("What is your choice?");

        int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine(); // get rid of newline

        // Allow the user to re-enter data
        while (choice < ADD || choice > QUIT)
        {
            System.out.println("You must choose a value between 1 and 3");
            System.out.println("Please re-enter your choice");
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        return choice;
    }

    public static int addNewEmail(ArrayList<String> data, int size, String insertMe)
    {
        if (data.binarySearch(data, 0, size, insertMe) > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("That email address has already been inserted");
            return size; // already in array
        }

        if (size == data.size())
        {
            System.out.println("Too many addresses are stored");
            return size; // the array is full already
        }

        // This is essentially one inner loop of insertion sort
        int index;
        for (index = size; index > 0 && data.get(index-1).compareTo(insertMe) > 0; --index)
        {
            data.add(index, data.get(index-1));
        }

        data.add(index, insertMe);

        return size+1;
    }
```

}

Comment: Where did you find this `binarySearch` method?

Comment: Don't dump the whole file, just post the relevant parts

Comment: `ArrayList` does not have a `binarySearch` method.  There are binary search methods elsewhere that can be applied to `ArrayList`, but it's not clear if you intended to use those?

Comment: I see, I was trying to use binarySearch from the collections class, but I understand that is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` does not have a `binarySearch` method. You can try this instead

```
if (Collections.binarySearch(data, insertMe) > 0)
```

This compiles, but I haven't read your code in enough detail to say it's definitely what you want to do.